# How to integrate Facebook into iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

I know this is an often-asked question; but my point is this: what is the recommended or well-proven way to connect to FB from iPhone App.

Type 1: I saw the tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app). It uses AsiHttpRequest, Json libraries to post on FB wall.

Type 2: There is a tutorial [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#graph) on Facebook site itself, which is using the same Graph API, but seems to be using different API calls to post on wall, logging in, etc.

Which of the above two is better? Type-1 uses external libraries but the tutorial is quite explanatory. Type-2 seems to be directly from Facebook, but then no idea how updated/outdated the tutorial is (no date indicated).

Comment: The most recommended way to develop for facebook is the new Facebook iOS SDK. http://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Comment: USe graph APIs Type2, the recommended way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type 2 was updated last Tuesday and type 1 was updated in January 2010, so I would suggest using Type 2 a) because the code is directly from Facebook and b) it is the most recent tutorial.

But, the best way to integrate Facebook is to use the new iOS 6 [Facebook SDK](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios6/).

Comment: iOS 6 is in beta why are u recommending this?

Comment: iOS 6 has Facebook integration, so you download iOS 6 Beta SDKs and then submit it when iOS 6 comes out.

Comment: +1 Thanks! It helped! That was a useful note on iOS6 FB integration. However, if the App has to support iOS5, we cannot leverage this inbuilt iOS-FB API, sadly though.

Answer (score 1):

The way to go is to download the [facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/ios/) for ios (and RTFM there :-)). If you are using ios 5 compile the lib as a static lib. Link your lib to your project and create some class wrappers to publish your app content into facebook. I haven't check the tutorial from Ray Wenderlich but you can  probably try to do his tut with the facebook API you have build your own and is the most recent.

Comment: The build part is explain here btw: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/