# How to share text and image on facebook wall (objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am working on an app which provides user to share the details of their app into facebook . I have UITableview where it contains the list of author name and when u click on book name it goes to another `UITableView` where it shows the different book of that author in each `TableViewCell`. I'm able to display the list in 2nd `UITableView` . 
I wanted to know how to share the author name , book name and the image (2nd tableview details). 
I'm showing the code which does that .. 
So when the user wants to share the details, he will have to tap on the `UIButton` which is there in every cell of author `UITableView`.

```
didselectatindexpath

    NSDictionary *selectedAuthor = nil;

     NSArray *sectionArray=[mainIndexDictionary objectForKey:[allKeysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        selectedAuthor = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        iPath=[[selectedAuthor objectForKey:@"SymptIndexID"] intValue];
        NSLog(@"iPath - %d",iPath);

        authortitleString=[[selectedAuthor objectForKey:@"authorIndexName"]stringByAppendingString:@" cure!"];
    }


    bookArray=[objDB customCellData:(NSInteger)iPath];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:authorView];
    [bookTableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0,10.0) animated:NO];

    [bookTableView reloadData]

;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In ios 6.0
you can achieve as follows (you must add the [social framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233) to your project)

```
 #import <Social/Social.h>

 - (void)ShareFacebook
 {
    SLComposeViewController *fbController=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
{
    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

        [fbController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        switch(result){
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            default:
            {
                NSLog(@"Cancelled.....");
               // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];

            }
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            {
                NSLog(@"Posted....");
            }
                break;
        }};


    [fbController setInitialText:@"This is My Sample Text"];


    [fbController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
    [self presentViewController:fbController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sign in!" message:@"Please first Sign In!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]autorelease];
    [alert show];
 }
}
```

Comment: go through the link http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_iOS_6_Facebook_Integration_Tutorial_using_UIActivityViewController

Comment: how can i post my current location??

Answer (score 1):

your question is a bit unclear but you can use this code for publishing text and image to Fb considering you have implemented all the others methods of FB ios Api correctly

```
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       APP_NAME,@"text", fb_app_url,@"href", nil], nil];
NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               APP_NAME, @"name",
                               fb_app_url, @"link",
                               fb_publish_image, @"picture",
                               APP_NAME, @"name",
                               @"Awesome APP", @"caption",
                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I am  loving it", GAME_NAME], @"description",
                               @"Get it now!",  @"message",
                               actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                               nil];

[self.faceBook dialog:@"stream.publish" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

for further details to implement fb api you can see

[How to integrate Facebook into iPhone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931897/how-to-integrate-facebook-into-iphone-app)[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931897/how-to-integrate-facebook-into-iphone-app)

this link shows the parameters allowed while publishing a message
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/

Comment: I want to display the title name which i get from iPath and the details of the iPath (book name , genre etc) .. the details are fetched from the sql db .. i wanted to know how to go about it

Comment: just replace the 2nd arg in actionlinks with iPath the 3rd arg is for image that can be fetched through a URL (you can put all the images in  Urls and access them through XMLs)if you dont have any hosting and you want to post static image inside the xcode project to wall you have to see Facebook api there are some methods there that allow image data to be posted